# Book about two guys who are captured by dwarves or goblins, and build Icarus-like wings to escape with

Tags: story-identification, books

When I was a kid, I used to read this German book (but maybe it also exists in English) where these two guys would travel a lot and search for something (I don't really know what they searched for, maybe a magical flower or something). While they traveled, they defeated a lot of dangers, for example a magical Mountain.

Later in the book, they were captured by dwarves or goblins or something like that, and they had (in the cave they were held captive in) a pillow and some candles, so they built wings for themselves to escape with.

The escape failed, but the wings worked, so they had to work for the goblins/dwarves and collect pine cones from the trees. In exchange for the work, the dwarves let them go, and they flew with their wings back home. The younger one flew too close to the Sun and fell, but I think the older one was able to save the younger one.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?